# Lie algebra of the group of biholomorphisms

Tags: differential-geometry, complex-geometry

Consider a complex manifold $X$ and $Aut(X)$ the Lie group of biholomorphisms of $X$. I want to calculate the Lie algebra of this Lie groups so as to derive a result analogue in the holomorphic realm to that for real smooth manifolds, namely
$$
\text{Lie}(\text{Diff}(M)) \simeq \mathfrak{X}(M)
$$
i.e. that infinitesimal diffeomorphisms are given by smooth vector fields. In the real case, one would take a 1-parameter family of diffeomorphisms $f_t$ close to the identity and argue that at each point, taking the derivative gives a tangent vector $\gamma'_p(0) = \frac{d}{dt}|_{t=0} f_t(p)$, and after some calculations, deduce that this induces a smooth field of vectors over $M$.

For the holomorphic case, I suspect that the infinitesimal biholomorphisms of a complex manifold correspond to **holomorphic vector fields**, namely holomorphic sections of the complex vector bundle $T^{1,0}X \rightarrow X$ endowed with the natural holomorphic structure coming from $X$.

However, I don't know how to prove that the derivative $\gamma'_p(0)$ above is in a natural way a (1,0)-vector in $T\underline{X}_\mathbb{C}=T^{1,0}X \oplus T^{0,1}X$ (where $\underline{X}$ is the smooth manifold underlying $X$).

Comment: Note that biholomorphisms of the unit disk form a real three-dimensional group. Consequently, automorphisms of the disk do not form a complex Lie group, and differentiating a one-parameter subgroup cannot generally yield a holomorphic vector field, since a finite-dimensional space of holomorphic vector fields is even-dimensional over the reals. (The space of holomorphic vector fields on the disk is infinite-dimensional.) <> Kobayashi's _Transformation Groups in Differential Geometry_ is a worthwhile read.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, this already tells me the question was too ambitious. I will check the book, perhaps there are interesting examples when further properties or structures are assumed for the complex manifold.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that your intuition is correct, but the question is a bit subtle. FIrst of all, there are topological obstructions for the group of biholomorphisms to be a complex Lie group, as pointed out in the comment by Andrew Hwang. One simple case in which such obstructions vanish (and to be honest, the only one I ever studied in any detail) is when the manifold is compact.

So, assume for the moment we have a compact manifold $X$, together with a complex structure $J$. I will denote by $\operatorname{Aut}(X,J)$ the group of biholomorphisms. A $1$-parameter subgroup, say $\{f_t\mid t\in\mathbb{R}\}\subset\operatorname{Aut}(X,J)$ gives you a vector field $v$ on $X$ by setting $$v_p:=\partial_{t=0}f_t(p).$$ Notice that this is just a real vector field, i.e. a section of $TX\to X$. As $f_t^*J=J$, we see however that $v$ satisfies \begin{equation}\label{realhol}
\tag{$\star$}
\mathcal{L}_vJ=0
\end{equation}
and for any $v$ that satisfies \eqref{realhol}, its flow $f_t$ will be a subgroup of $\operatorname{Aut}(X,J)$ - the flow will be complete, as $X$ is compact. I guess we can already see that this might be a problem for noncompact manifolds.

Sections of $TX$ that satisfy \eqref{realhol} are usually called *real-holomorphic vector fields*. From this point of view then, the lie algebra of $\operatorname{Aut}(X,J)$ is the algebra of real-holomorphic vector fields. Notice however that:

1. if $v$ is real-holomorphic, also $Jv$ is;
2. $v$ is real-holomorphic if and only if $v^{1,0}$ is holomorphic, meaning that it is a holomorphic section of the holomorphic vector bundle $T^{1,0}X$.

So we can identify the Lie algebra of $\operatorname{Aut}(X,J)$ either with holomorphic or real-holomorphic vector fields, and it has a complex structure coming either from remark $1$ above, if you like to use real-holomorphic vector fields, or just from multiplication by $i$, if you prefer holomorphic vector fields. However, we are still missing an useful tool, as one might wonder what the complex analogue of the flow of a real-holomorphic vector field is.

So, let $v^{1,0}$ be a holomorphic vector field, and consider the real-holomorphic vector fields $v$ and $Jv$. notice that
\begin{equation}
v=2\,\Re(v^{1,0})$\mbox{ and }Jv=-2\,\Im(v^{1,0})
\end{equation}
and notice also that by \eqref{realhol}, $[v,Jv]=0$. So the flows of $v$ and $Jv$ commute; call them $f^v_t$ and $f^{Jv}_s$, and consider the composition
\begin{equation}
\Phi_{z}:=f^v_t\circ f^{Jv}_s,\ \mbox{ for }z=t+\operatorname{i}s
\end{equation}
Then $\Phi_z$ is a subgroup of $\operatorname{Aut}(X,J)$, and it can be checked that for any $p\in M$, $$v^{1,0}_p=\partial_{z=0}\Phi_z(p).$$
In other words, $\Phi_z$ is the "complex flow" of the holomorphic vector field $v^{1,0}$.

Comment: I could have never expected such a detailed answer. Superb! Thank you @Johny Lemmon! 

As I understand, the complex flow gives an additive complex subgroup $\Phi_z\circ \Phi_{z'} = \Phi_{z+z'}$ using the commutativity of $f^v$ and $f^{jv}$.

For further reference: is there any book where can I find these notions? I am reading Well's, Huybrechts and some Kobayashi's but I couldn't find any reference towards this construction you just developed.

Comment: If I remember correctly, I first learned of this reading this paper by LeBrun and Simanca https://eudml.org/doc/58166 see page 303, middle of the page. There is a two-line paragraph briefly explaining what I've written above. My guess however is that this construction is somewhat well-known in complex geometry, and probably first appeared elsewhere. It could be worth while looking for something similar in Kobayashi-Nomizu vol 2, but I wouldn't know where to look precisely. Also a good general reference for the Kähler-oriented people are Paul Gauduchon's notes.